# Is it possible to count the amount of matching strings in a given text when using a fulltext index?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

It's actually a pretty simple problem I ran into.
Image we have a node with the properties title and description.
Now on this node was created a fulltext index which was used to find the nodes containing a specific string.

After returning the results to the frontend I need to order the results, not only by score but by the amount of matching strings within the description or title. So for example if the string "customer" appeared in one node four times it's ordered higher than the node in which the string only appeared once.
You could also search for non-existing words that only match via fuzzy-search.

Is there a way to implement this with the fuzzy-search/wildcard search of the fulltext index?

I haven't found anything regarding this subject so I was wondering if any of you have maybe an idea on how to solve this.